# 2 IE8 Webpage views - Look completely different? Why?

Tags: mobile, internet-explorer-8, meta-tags

Here's the original page that I coded using "Adaptive Design", and has no support for mobile devices:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/savedateIE8/index.html

Looks great in IE 8 as it should via the pic below:

[image: IE 8 Looking good]

Here's a page that I optimized for mobile devices, basically it is EXACTLY the same as the first page, except it adds in `<meta>` tags and such for mobile devices.  Looks good in all browsers that I test, except IE 7 (which I could care less about), and IE 8 (WHICH I REALLY CARE ABOUT)  A lot of people visit the site using IE 8, so it needs to support IE 8!:  http://opportunityfinance.net/conference-2013/index.html

Pic of what it looks like in IE 8 below:

[image: IE 8 Nightmare for supporting Mobile devices]

Why is this looking completely different in IE 8 than the first pic?  I can't understand it.  AFAIK, it should be loading up the index.css file and applying it exactly like the first page.  What is the problem here?

Could it possibly be related to this bit of code:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

But if I remove that code than it looks all jacked up in IE 9 also!

**EDIT**:  Please do not edit my code changing IE 8 to IE 9.  I understand that this problem is being tested in IE 9, but it is using `IE 8 Document Mode` in Developer Tools, so it is the same as IE 8!

Comment: try closing the `<meta .... />` with `/>` or `</meta>`. This works for me on your URL with IE9, compatibility mode to IE8, IE8 standards

Comment: @IvayloSlavov - Have done this and it did not make any difference, page still renders horrible in IE8 Document Mode!  OMG!

Comment: try cleaning the cache, maybe that is the problem. IE is a pain you know

Comment: Are you telling me that it views fine for you in IE8 Document mode??

Comment: I cleared my cache, deleted all cookies, cleared EVERYTHING!  But the page still renders exactly the same in IE 8 Document Mode!

Comment: well It looked good on mine, but it may have been me who had cached page. Check this out: http://dorward.me.uk/www/ie8/. It seems the presence of `X-UA-Compatible` headers make IE8 ignore the DOCTYPE declaration, which results in random "effects" on html compatibility

Comment: How can I use javascript or jQuery to input this into the head for only IE9 browsers?  Or Not input it into the head for IE8- browsers?  Or better yet, just redirect to the other page if IE 8 and below!

Comment: If I were you, I'd remove the meta on IE8, and keep the markup for other browsers. As for browser detection, try this for IE: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ - you can use it around any markup

Comment: How to remove the meta tag for IE 8?

Comment: <!--[if !IE 8]>
 <meta ....>
<![endif]-->

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27349/discussion-between-ivaylo-slavov-and-solomon-closson)

Comment: Well, the problem is NOT RELATED to this:  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

Comment: I know this because I removed it completely from the document, cleared cache and cookies, but problem still exists!!!  I believe it is loading up the wrong stylesheet, for reasons unknown...  Seems to be loading up the `narrow.css` stylesheet instead of `index.css`.

Comment: The problem exists in IE 8 Document Mode ONLY, but doesn't exist in IE 8 Browser Mode (Don't really understand the difference between the 2 however)

Comment: Which is why I need to redirect, to the other page for IE 8, cause I don't understand what is causing the problem!  removing the `<meta>` tag for `X-UA-Compatible` does NOT HELP ANY!

Comment: see chat, we have too many comments here

Comment: Whoever is editing my question so that it says `IE 9` instead of `IE 8`, please correct yourself.  The problem is in IE 8, not IE 9.  I am testing it with IE 9, but with IE 8 Document Mode Compatibility!  So it is the equivalent of `IE 8`.  If you are seeing this problem in IE9, than you need to change the `Document mode` to use IE 9!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's how I solved this problem.  Apparently any version of IE before IE 9 does not attach the stylesheet when using `media queries` inside of the `link` tags `media` attribute.  Also, IE 8- had some odd behavior when presented with this line: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`  And as it turns out, I don't even need this line:  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` which was causing problems since the Google Chrome Frame wasn't available, and edge wasn't either.  So, I just removed that line, and all is fine now.

Here's the dirty hack I had to do in order to get this working for mobile devices and IE 7 and 8, for anyone interested:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<!--<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/narrow.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 600px)" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 601px)" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 601px)" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I wish there was an `else` statement in these conditionals, but whatever.  This works now and loads up the index.css file and thank god, cause I was pulling out my hair on this one!  The `narrow.css` file doesn't need any conditionals, since IE 7 and 8 ignore the stylesheet anyways cause it uses media queries.