# How to detect in jQuery's latest version if browser is msie 8 and below?

Tags: jquery, browser, internet-explorer-8

Am using the latest build of the jQuery 1.x versions.  I believe they removed `$.browser` support in the latest version.  So how can I do this via jQuery?  Or is my information incorrect?

I need to target a script for MSIE 8 and below only!

Comment: Don't. Detect the feature, not the browser. If the method doesn't exist, conditionally execute the necessary code. :)
What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Redirect to another webpage using `window.location.href` I have asked another question but haven't gotten any answers, and I'm not able to determine the EXACT PROBLEM in IE 8:  questions located here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748241/2-ie8-webpage-views-look-completely-different-why

Comment: Please elaborate what you are trying to accomplish. What problem are you trying to solve? A well asked question is simple to answer.

Comment: @Swordfish0321 - Have you looked at the question I asked in my previous comment linking to the question?  I think I've elaborated just about everything on that!  I can't understand the problem with IE 8 on that page.  No one else can either!  So, I need to REDIRECT to the page where IE 8 actually works in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional statements in your markup up to load a specific versions of jQuery if the user is on IE 8 or lower.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.X.X/jquery.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This will perform what you are asking to do, but as the other folks on here are saying this isn't exactly the best way to handle the issue. Detecting the feature or using a library like moderizer is probably your best approach.

Comment: Is there a conditional statement for ONLY IE8 and not any others?

Comment: Yeah, just say <!--[if IE 8]>

Comment: This doesn't help me unfortunately.  See this question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748241/2-ie8-webpage-views-look-completely-different-why

Comment: After reading this post I'm still not sure what your problem is. Please post specific code examples either in this story or the other so others can identify where the error might be occurring. While screens are nice, they are not a supplement for code.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

> The `jQuery.browser()` method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and
>   is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery
>   Migrate plugin. We recommend using feature detection with a library
>   such as Modernizr.

However, I strongly suggest to use feature detection instead of browser sniffing to conditionnaly execute code depending on what the browser supports. If you want to learn more about it, here's an [interesting article](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/).

Comment: I need to change the `window.location.href` property in IE 8 and lower preferrably!

Comment: And what are you doing in modern browsers instead?

Answer (score 0):

> For your own project's feature-detection needs, we strongly recommend
>   the use of an external library such as Modernizr instead of dependency
>   on properties in jQuery.support.

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/#entry-longdesc